# Regular number Machin-like formula for pi?

Tags: number-theory, taylor-expansion

Let a regular number $x$, be a positive integer number such that there is a power $k$ of ten, such that $10^k$ is divisible by $x$. They have the form $x=2^i 5^j$ and the decimal expansion of $1/x$ will be finite.

Example: $1/25=0.04$ (see also OEIS sequence [A003592](https://oeis.org/A003592))

Obviously if $1/x$ is a regular number reziprocal, all its powers are also regular number reziprocal. Proof: if $10^k$ is divided by $x$, then $10^{n k}$ is divided by $x^n$. This helps in computing taylor series.

I am curently using the following formula due to Euler:

$$\pi = 20 \arctan(\frac{1}{7})+8 \arctan(\frac{3}{79})$$

But the arguments to arctan (1/7 and 3/79) are not regular number reziprocals in the above. Any suggestion for doing something with regular number reziprocals for $\pi$. Is it possible?

Comment: Seems implausible but i have no disproof as yet .

Answer (score 1):

If
$xyz+1=yz+zx+xy+x+y+z$
then
$\tan^{-1}{\frac1x}+\tan^{-1}{\frac1y}+\tan^{-1}{\frac1z}=\frac{\pi}4.$

Also, if
$xyzu+x+y+z+u+1=$
$(zu(x+y)+xy(z+u)+$
$x(y+z+u)+y(z+u)+zu)$
then
$\tan^{-1}{\frac1x}+\tan^{-1}{\frac1y}+\tan^{-1}{\frac1z}+\tan^{-1}{\frac1u}=\frac{\pi}4.$

Comment: Do you say you can find x,y,z each of the form 2^i*5^j for some i,j ?

Comment: No, it is just a test which is easily made in a systematic search for Machin-type formulæ.

Comment: Those Machin-type formulæ with c0=1, c1=1, c2=1 and c3=1 ?

Comment: The only ones I found are: (2, 4, 13); (2, 5, 8); and (3, 3, 7).

Answer (score 0):

Was using complex numbers to find solutions of two simple regular number summands Machin-like formulas for pi. Here is a selection:

$$tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{4})+tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{5}) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$tan^{-1}(\frac{9}{16})+tan^{-1}(\frac{7}{25})=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$tan^{-1}(\frac{61}{64})+tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{125})=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

The idea behind using complex numbers, is that we can use the argument of a complex number for the arcus tangent of a rational number:

$$tan^{-1}(w) = arg(\overline{w}) \quad where \quad w = \frac{y}{x} \quad and \quad \overline{w} = x+i\,y$$

This further allows using complex multiplication as follows:

$$tan^{-1}(z)+tan^{-1}(t) = arg(\overline{z}\,\overline{t})$$

And for the result of the multiplication we have:

$$x = y \quad implies\quad arg(\overline{w})=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

For $z=a_1+i\,b_1$ and $t=a_2+i\,b_2$ this leads to the following equation:

$$a_1\,a_2-b_1\,b_2 = b_1\,a_2+a_1\,b_2$$

We can now substitute regular numbers for $a_1,a_2$ and try to solve the equation. For example we can try $a_1=5, a_2=4$ and indeed find a solution:

$$20 - b_1\,b_2 = b_1\,4+5\,b_2$$

We then find $b_1=3, b_2=1$, thus:

$$tan^{-1}(\frac{3}{5})+tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{4}) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

The method can be extended for Machin-like formula factors $c_i \neq 1$ by simply taking powers of the complex numbers, or using more than two complex numbers for $n>2$.

Comment: Can we break out of the pattern: tan-1(a/2^i) + tan-1(b/5^j) = π/4 ?